# Восстановить БД mySQL из дампа кроме определенной таблицы

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Сделал дамп очень большой БД.

```
mysqldump -uroot user1_db --opt --routines --lock-tables | gzip > /backup/user1_db.sql.gz
```

Восстанавливаю обычно таким образом:

```
gunzip < /backup/user1_db.sql.gz | mysql -uroot user1_db
```

Вопрос: как восстановить всю базу (включая хранимые процедуры) из дампа, кроме определенной таблицы table1?

Comment: Дамп это просто текстовый файл с sql-запросами, так что наверное руками удалить нежелательные запросы из дампа

Comment: увы нереально. Файл ооооочень большой.

Comment: поиском найдите create table. ту, где нужная и следующую. И все между ними выбросьте. Какая разница какого размера файл

Comment: Надо было пропускать эту таблицу при создании дампа. Сейчас увы - либо восстанавливать всё, либо вырезать из дампа таблицу в текстовом процессоре.

Answer (score 0):

Если в дампе перед созданием таблиц у вас добавлены комментарии такого рода:

```
Table structure for table TABLE_NAME
```

То можно исключить ненужную таблицу таким образом:

```
gunzip < /backup/user1_db.sql.gz | sed -r -e '/Table structure for table `table1/,/Table structure/d;' |  mysql -uroot user1_db
```

Comment: а если таблица последняя в дампе?

Comment: а если последняя то так: gunzip < /backup/user1_db.sql.gz | sed -r -e '/Table structure for table `table1/,/Dump completed/d;' |  mysql -uroot user1_db